# HTML JQuery Maphilight not hilighting - don't know why

Tags: jquery, html, maphilight

On my page http://www.veniria.esy.es/#veniria i have an image map with JQuery maphilight plugin. It was working totally fine, until I have added main page to the site. Now it's not working at all, like JQuery is not detecting mouseover, because this don't work either:

```
$('#linkAbhaeghar').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('#abhaegharMap').mouseover();
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    $('#abhaegharMap').mouseout();
}).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

and buttons on the right are not hilighting.

Comment: For some reason the canvas over your map has width and height set to zero. If you wait for the map to show up and run this in console: $('canvas').css({
 'width': '',
 'height': ''
}); it starts to show the regions again

Comment: Most likely the reason being your second page is hidden on page load.

Comment: I know it propably is, but why? And what can I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you running the `$("#veniria").maphilight();` on document ready.
But on document ready the map is hidden and therefore the canvas gets width and height set to zero.
You need to change the:

```
$("#pageMain").fadeIn(500);
```

To:

```
$("#pageMain").fadeIn(500, function(){
    $("#veniria").maphilight();
});
```

In both

```
function hash() {
    if(window.location.hash == "#veniria") {
        $(".page").fadeOut(500).promise().done(function(){
            $("#pageMain").fadeIn(500, function(){
                $("#veniria").maphilight();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And

```
$("#menuMain").click(function(){
    $(".page").fadeOut(500).promise().done(function(){
        $("#pageMain").fadeIn(500, function(){
            $("#veniria").maphilight();
        });
    });
});
```